# how to go through json result without using ngFor angular

Tags: angular

I have JSON result which i get it from the back-end it gives me the following result

```
[
   {
      "status":"RUN",
      "numberOfTurbines":1
   },
   {
      "status":"ERROR",
      "numberOfTurbines":20
   },
   {
      "status":"STOP",
      "numberOfTurbines":5
   },
   {
      "status":"START_UP",
      "numberOfTurbines":2
   }
]
```

I have 4 cards with icons that indicate each status(Run,error,STOP,Start_up) in my ts component I have:

```
this.service.getAllTurbinesStat().subscribe(s=>{
  this.allStats = s;
});
```

in my html:

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
<mat-card class="cards">
   <mat-card-title style="color:red;">RUN</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
<mat-card  class="cards">
   <span class="material-icons">
     pan_tool
   </span>
   <mat-card-title>ERROR</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
<mat-card  class="cards ">
   <span class="material-icons">
   build_circle
   </span>
   <mat-card-title>STOP</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
<mat-card  class="cards">
   <span class="material-icons" >
     arrow_circle_down
   </span>
   <mat-card-title>Start_up</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

I just want to get the respective data and put in each card, how can I achieve?*ngFor I know goes through data but how can I get the field data that I want?numberOfTurbines and status

Comment: if you are sure you will get this data only. then sort your result with status(not required) and show data with indexing. ex. this.allStats[0].status will return RUN and this.allStats[0].numberOfTurbines will return 1.

Comment: @HPSingh i dont need ngFor then?

Comment: Yes, you don't need ngFor. You will get data from array "this.allStats" by index.

Comment: @SamScholefield answer looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you not use `*ngFor`?

```js
const turbines = [] // your array of JSON objects
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let turbine of turbines">
  <mat-card>
    <p>Status: {{ turbine.status }} </p>
    <p>Turbines: {{ turbine.numberOfTurbines }}</p>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```